# Return Value From Data Frame in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

i have a data frame for the correlation values between several items and i want to make a shiny app for my case to give it the first item and the second item and its return the value of the correlation between them and represent this result in color i.e If the value of the correlation Is larger than 50 then the color of this number will be green and if this value is less than 50 then this number will be red one .
this's a sample from my DF

```
 DF<- structure(list(row = structure(1:100, .Label = c(" Fagr Mango", 
" Green Beans", "10075 - Bashmala", "Adalia Lemon", "African Crimson Grape", 
"African Pear", "Amar Eldain 400G", "Amar Eldain 400G Old", "American Plum", 
"Apricot", "Artichoke old", "Arugula", "Arugula old", "Arugula Rokla Old", 
"Autumn Royal Grape", "Avocado", "Baladi Cabbage", "Baladi Garlic", 
"Banati Grape", "Barbary Figs", "Barhi Dates", "Barshomi Figs", 
"Beet", "Black Eggplant", "Broccoli", "Cantaloupe", "Capsicum", 
"Carrot", "Cauliflower", "Chard", "Chard Old", "Cherry Tomatoes", 
"Chili Pepper", "Chinese Garlic", "Classic Eggplant", "coconut", 
"Cooking Potato", "Coriander", "Coriander old", "Crimson Grape", 
"Cucumber", "Deluxe Dried Dates", "Dessert Peach", "Dill", "Dill old", 
"Doum", "Dried Apricot", "Dried Dates", "Dried Figs 400G", "Dried Figs 400G Old", 
"Dried Plum", "Flame Grape", "Florida Peach", "Fons Mango", "Fruit Lovers", 
"Fruit Lovers Old", "frying Potato", "Gala Apple", "Ginger", 
"Ginger Old", "Golden Apple", "Golden Onion", "Golden Raisin", 
"Granny Apple", "Grape Leaves", "Greek Red Apple", "Greek sugar apple", 
"Green Latoga Lettuce  Old", "Green pepper", "Guava", "Hendi Mango", 
"Hibiscus", "Hollywood Plum", "Hot Pepper", "Iceberg Lettuce", 
"Iceberg Lettuce old", "Imported Apricot", "Imported Banana", 
"Imported Celery old", "Imported Cherry", "Imported Leek", "Imported Leek Old", 
"Imported Nectarine", "Imported Peach", "Imported Pear", "Ismalilia Fass Mango", 
"Italian Basil Old", "Japanese Plum", "Kaka", "Kathaa", "kiwi", 
"Large Fruit Box", "Large Fruit Box Old", "Lebanese Apple", "Leek", 
"Local Apple", "Local Banana", "Local Celery ", "Local Cucumber", 
"Local Eggplant", "Local Hot Pepper", "Local Lemon", "Local Pear", 
"Maya Mango", "Medium Fruit Box", "Medium Fruit Box Old", "Melon", 
"Mexican Chili Pepper", "Mint", "Mint old", "Molokhia", "Momtaza Mango", 
"Momtaza Owais Mango", "Morket Tangerine", "Mushroom (200G)", 
"Mushroom (200G) old", "Naoumi Mango", "Navel Orange", "Nectarine Peach", 
"Nems Watermelon (KG)", "Okra", "Orange celery", "Orange For Juice", 
"Owais Mango", "Pack Of celery", "Parsle old", "Parsley", "Pineapple ( per KG)", 
"Polandian Apple", "Pomegranate", "Processing Peas ", "Pumpkin", 
"Raisin", "Red Cabbage", "Red Cabbage old", "Red Garlic", "Red Globe Grape", 
"Red Onion", "Red Radish", "Red Radish old", "Rosemary old", 
"Sadeeka Mango", "Santa Rosa Plum", "Saturn Nectarine", "Saturn Peach", 
"Sesame Dates", "Shalanteah Cantaloupe", "sobya", "Sobya", "Sokkary Mango", 
"Spanish Plum", "Spanish red plum", "Strawberry", "Sudanese Banana ", 
"Sugary Peach", "Superior Grape", "Sweet Apple", "Sweet Potato", 
"Syrian Green Apple", "Syrian plum", "Tamr 700G", "Tamr 700G Old", 
"Tamr hendi", "Taro", "Thyme Old", "Tomato", "Watermelon ( per KG)", 
"White Cabbage", "White Cabbage Old", "White Eggplant ", "White Prime Grape", 
"Yasmina Mango", "Zaghlol Dates", "Zebdaya Mango", "Zucchini"
), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" Fagr Mango", 
" Green Beans", "10075 - Bashmala", "Adalia Lemon", "African Crimson Grape", 
"African Pear", "Amar Eldain 400G", "Amar Eldain 400G Old", "American Plum", 
"Apricot", "Artichoke old", "Arugula", "Arugula old", "Arugula Rokla Old", 
"Autumn Royal Grape", "Avocado", "Baladi Cabbage", "Baladi Garlic", 
"Banati Grape", "Barbary Figs", "Barhi Dates", "Barshomi Figs", 
"Beet", "Black Eggplant", "Broccoli", "Cantaloupe", "Capsicum", 
"Carrot", "Cauliflower", "Chard", "Chard Old", "Cherry Tomatoes", 
"Chili Pepper", "Chinese Garlic", "Classic Eggplant", "coconut", 
"Cooking Potato", "Coriander", "Coriander old", "Crimson Grape", 
"Cucumber", "Deluxe Dried Dates", "Dessert Peach", "Dill", "Dill old", 
"Doum", "Dried Apricot", "Dried Dates", "Dried Figs 400G", "Dried Figs 400G Old", 
"Dried Plum", "Flame Grape", "Florida Peach", "Fons Mango", "Fruit Lovers", 
"Fruit Lovers Old", "frying Potato", "Gala Apple", "Ginger", 
"Ginger Old", "Golden Apple", "Golden Onion", "Golden Raisin", 
"Granny Apple", "Grape Leaves", "Greek Red Apple", "Greek sugar apple", 
"Green Latoga Lettuce  Old", "Green pepper", "Guava", "Hendi Mango", 
"Hibiscus", "Hollywood Plum", "Hot Pepper", "Iceberg Lettuce", 
"Iceberg Lettuce old", "Imported Apricot", "Imported Banana", 
"Imported Celery old", "Imported Cherry", "Imported Leek", "Imported Leek Old", 
"Imported Nectarine", "Imported Peach", "Imported Pear", "Ismalilia Fass Mango", 
"Italian Basil Old", "Japanese Plum", "Kaka", "Kathaa", "kiwi", 
"Large Fruit Box", "Large Fruit Box Old", "Lebanese Apple", "Leek", 
"Local Apple", "Local Banana", "Local Celery ", "Local Cucumber", 
"Local Eggplant", "Local Hot Pepper", "Local Lemon", "Local Pear", 
"Maya Mango", "Medium Fruit Box", "Medium Fruit Box Old", "Melon", 
"Mexican Chili Pepper", "Mint", "Mint old", "Molokhia", "Momtaza Mango", 
"Momtaza Owais Mango", "Morket Tangerine", "Mushroom (200G)", 
"Mushroom (200G) old", "Naoumi Mango", "Navel Orange", "Nectarine Peach", 
"Nems Watermelon (KG)", "Okra", "Orange celery", "Orange For Juice", 
"Owais Mango", "Pack Of celery", "Parsle old", "Parsley", "Pineapple ( per KG)", 
"Polandian Apple", "Pomegranate", "Processing Peas ", "Pumpkin", 
"Raisin", "Red Cabbage", "Red Cabbage old", "Red Garlic", "Red Globe Grape", 
"Red Onion", "Red Radish", "Red Radish old", "Rosemary old", 
"Sadeeka Mango", "Santa Rosa Plum", "Saturn Nectarine", "Saturn Peach", 
"Sesame Dates", "Shalanteah Cantaloupe", "sobya", "Sobya", "Sokkary Mango", 
"Spanish Plum", "Spanish red plum", "Strawberry", "Sudanese Banana ", 
"Sugary Peach", "Superior Grape", "Sweet Apple", "Sweet Potato", 
"Syrian Green Apple", "Syrian plum", "Tamr 700G", "Tamr 700G Old", 
"Tamr hendi", "Taro", "Thyme Old", "Tomato", "Watermelon ( per KG)", 
"White Cabbage", "White Cabbage Old", "White Eggplant ", "White Prime Grape", 
"Yasmina Mango", "Zaghlol Dates", "Zebdaya Mango", "Zucchini"
), class = "factor"), corr = c(100, 0, 0, 16.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 33.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67, 16.67, 33.33, 
0, 16.67, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.67, 0, 33.33, 0, 0, 16.67, 
0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 16.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 33.33, 
33.33, 0, 0, 16.67, 0, 0, 0, 16.67, 0, 0, 0, 33.33, 0, 33.33, 
0, 0, 16.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33.33, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.67, 0, 0)), .Names = c("row", "col", 
"corr"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

and i tried to do this but i didn't get the result.
this's my ui.R code

```
library(shiny)
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Item Correlation"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Item2","Select First Item",choices= DF$row)
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Item","Select Second Item",choices= DF$col),

  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("Itemcorr")
  )
)
)
```

and this's Server.R code

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$Itemcorr<- renderTable({
    ItemFilter<- subset(DF, DF$row ==input$item2)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some issues in your code

- The input id `Item` appears twice in `ui.R`
- The table-output is called `Itemcorr` in `server.R` and `DF$corr` in `ui.R`.
- I am pretty sure `input` and `output` IDs should not contain special characters like `$`.
- You use `input$item` in `server.R` but don't define `item` anywhere in `ui.R`. Did you mean to use `Item`?
- You have two `sidebarPanel`s in `ui.R`
- `mainPanel` is wrapped inside `sidebarPanel`
- The use of `DF$corr` in `server.R` does not make sense to me. Did you mean to use `DF$col`?
- The expression in `renderTable` does not return a dataframe.

Please spend more time reading the basic shiny documentation before posting questions on SO. Since I already took a look, here is a working vesion of your app. Hoepuffy it does what you intended.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Item Correlation"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Item2","Select First Item",choices= DF$row),
    selectInput("Item","Select Second Item",choices= DF$col)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("Itemcorr")
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({
    subset(DF, DF$col == input$Item)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, i will edit my code to correct my mistakes. can i return one value only not a table ? as an ex when i select  "Adalia Lemon" in the first item and select "Fagr Mango" in the second item then the returned value is (16.67). and so on

Comment: It is possible, but it would be better to use `renderText/textOutput` for that.